# Convert html entity to decimal value using visual C#

Tags: c#, special-characters, html-entities

i need to convert special html entities to its decimal values using visual C#. First i need to  load .html file and need to replace all special character values to decimal values.

EX: ‰ ---> "&#137"
    ® ---> "&#174"

    Å ---> "&#197"

so what is the optimized way to replace all characters with decimal values. i have list of more than 1000 characters and entities.

Comment: I would assume that not all elements are special characters? `<div>100&#137</div>` is 1 Html element, 3 characters, 1 special character?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`WebUtility.HtmlEncode Method (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can comfortably fit your HTML file in a `StringBuilder`, you could take a couple of different approaches.  First, I'm assuming you have all of your character replacements stored in a dictionary:

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<char,string> {
  { '®', "&#137" },
  // ...etc
}
```

First, read your file into a `StringBuilder`:

```
var html = new StringBuilder( File.ReadAllText( filename ) );
```

The first approach is that you could use `StringBuilder.Replace(string,string)`:

```
foreach( var c in replacements.Keys ) {
  html.Replace( c.ToString(), replacements[c] );
}
```

The second approach would be to go through every character in the file and see if it needs replacing (note that we start backwards from the end of the file; if we went forwards, we'd constantly be having to modify our index value since we're adding length to the file):

```
for( int i=html.Length-1; i>0; i-- ) {
  var c = html[i];
  if( replacements.ContainsKey( c ) ) {
    html.Remove( i, 1 );
    html.Insert( i, replacements[c] );
  }
}
```

It's hard to say which would be more efficient without either having details about the implementation of `StringBuilder.Replace(string,string)` or doing some profiling, but I'll leave that up to you.

If it's not feasible to load your entire HTML file into a `StringBuilder`, you could use a variation of the second technique with a `StreamReader` reading the file one byte at a time.